# Can't spoof MAC address in a MacBook

Tags: mac-address, macos-high-sierra, mac-spoofing

I'm having some trouble spoofing my MAC address on my new MacBook Pro (OSX 10.13.6): it simply doesn't change -.-"

On my prevous MacBook I created and used this script:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Old MAC:"
sudo ifconfig en0 ether | grep ether

MAC=$(openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//')
sudo ifconfig en0 ether $MAC

echo "New MAC ($MAC):"
sudo ifconfig en0 ether | grep ether
```

It worked fine on my old MacBook, but after migrating my user to the new MacBook, the old and the new MAC addresses are the same. I also tried third party tools *(brew install spoof-mac)* with the same result.

If I try to spoof my MAC address now, the output is always like this, does't matter if the WIFI is connected, disconnected or disabled.

```
tim@Tim:~$ ./renewMac.sh
Old MAC:
    ether 88:e9:fe:83:XX:XX
New MAC (cd:4c:a0:01:9f:e4):
    ether 88:e9:fe:83:XX:XX
```

Any tips what is wrong configured?

Comment: Having the same issue: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/106768

Comment: same problem here

Comment: this is an issue for many users: https://github.com/feross/SpoofMAC/issues/87

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spoofing works again on Catalina (macOS 10.15) (thanks @[Life is complex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6083423/life-is-complex) & [source](https://github.com/feross/SpoofMAC/issues/87))

Answer (score 16):

What you can get from https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/106768 is:
It has been actively removed and Apple is not willing to restore it

It does not work with new devices (2018+), on these it does not even when used with external adapters (like USB-C to Ethernet Adapters).
So it is NOT caused by hardware, it's the combination of MacOS and new hardware that disables the feature.

I wonder if there is a way to trick MacOS in "thinking" that it deals with an older Mac. Maybe then it'll work again.

Answer (score 1):

Trying now on BigSur and it doesn't appear to work.